# PHP Mysql Left Join

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

```
<?php
$q = mysql_query("SELECT sub_cat.*, links.*
                 FROM links
                 LEFT JOIN sub_cat
                 ON links.p_id = sub_cat.id
                 WHERE sub_cat.p_id = '$id'
                 ORDER BY name ASC") or die (mysql_error());

while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
{
    $links_name = $r['name'];
    $link_h3 = $links_name != '' ? '<h3>' . $links_name . '</h3>' : '';
    //print $link_h3;
    print '<pre>';
    print_r ($r);
}
?>
```

I have two tables with rows like:

### sub_cat

- id
- name
- p_id

### links

- id
- links
- p_id

In sub cat i have movie categories, like foreign language movies, national movies, uncategorised movies and so on. In links table i have concrete movie links and depending on sub category.

The only thing is that i do not want dublicate titles (sub_cat.name).
result is:

> **Without Category** www.moviesite.com
>
> **Without Category** www.moviesite2.com
>
> **Without Category** www.moviesite3.com
>
> **Foreign Movies** www.moviesite1.bla
>
> **Foreign Movies** www.moviesite2.bla

**I want to be**

> **Without Category** www.moviesite.com
>
> www.moviesite2.com
>
> www.moviesite3.com
>
> **Foreign Movies** www.moviesite1.bla
>
> www.moviesite2.bla

and do not have any idea how to do this :(

any help appreciated.

Comment: you query is already fine. you should do it on the application level. specifically on this part: `while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do the job, you have 2 solutions:

The first solution is to process your data before showing it, in order to group all movies by category.

You can do for example:

```
$moviesByCategory = array();

while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
{
    // Create the new sub array for the new category if necessary
    if (!isset($moviesByCategory[$r['name']]))
        $moviesByCategory[$r['name']] = array();

    // Add the movie in the category
    $moviesByCategory[$r['name']][] = $r['links'];
}
```

And then, you can now iterate on this new array like

```
foreach($moviesByCategory as $category => $movies)
{
    // Print the category name
    echo '<h1>' . $category . '</h1>';

    // Print all movies of the category
    foreach($movies as $movie)
        echo '<h3>' . $movie . '</h3>';
}
```

The second solution is to modify the SQL query to group directly all movies that have the same category. You just have to use a `GROUP BY` clause on `sub_cat.id` and then apply an agregate function on all other fields in the select.

For performance aspect, the best solution is the SQL solution, but doing it with PHP will give you more flexibility for the presentation.

Comment: i made 1st solution and changed some things i needed and woked perfectly, just did what i wanted. thanks again

Answer (score -1):

Try something like:

```
$lastSubcatName = "";
while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
{
  $links_name = $r['name'];

  if($lastSubcatName != $links_name)
  {
    echo "<h1>".$links_name."</h1>";
    $lastSubcatName = $links_name;
  }

  echo '<h3>' . $r['links'] . '</h3>';
}
```

Comment: You don't know if the data is coming from the DB on the right order (all movies with the same category are not necessarily grouped

Comment: ORDER BY sub_cat.name ASC -- all links will return on the right order.

Comment: Indeed, it is correct thanks to the order. Skip my comments ;) but it stay robust-less as it depend on the order of the data.

Comment: I think for more robust-less in this code we need to use category_id, not category name: $moviesByCategory[$r['sub_cat.id']][] = $r['links']; because categories with different IDs but the same named may be differents entites :)

Comment: I agree that point, although in this case, catgory are alphabetically different.